# Measure the rate of growth of a crack from Video

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, video-processing

My experiment involves subjecting a substance to pressure that makes the substance eventually crack. The crack grows with time and pressure applied. I have a set-up to take a picture of the substance at fixed intervals of time.

I need to measure how fast crack grows.How do I go about this? (I can code in Python).

Is there a way to measure live speed or speed of growth of crack from one frame to another?
[image]

Google drive link to series of pictures taken - https://drive.google.com/open?id=189cv8B4rm3lhSgT6OYfI_aN0Xmqi-tYi

Kindly advise.

I Tried floodFill from OpenCV as per suggestions to this question. But the returned mask is as shown:

[image]

```
h, w = resized.shape[:2]
mask = np.zeros((h+2, w+2), np.uint8) 
seed = (int(w/2),int(h/2))

# Floodfill from point (0, 0)
num,im,mask,rect = cv2.floodFill(resized, mask, (0,0), (255,0,0), (10,)*3, (10,)*3, floodflags)
```

I thought if I can get the co-ordinates of the rectangle bounding box that encloses the crack, I can track its co-ordinates across frames and measure the size of the crack and eventually the speed.

I tried thresholding as below:

```
th, im_th = cv2.threshold(im, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY);
```

This gives:
[image]

I'm unsure if this will let me filter out the background and draw a bounding box over the crack alone. Please advise.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any question on image processing is going to be much better received if accompanied by images!

Comment: Modified the question now- https://drive.google.com/open?id=189cv8B4rm3lhSgT6OYfI_aN0Xmqi-tYi has the series of images taken

Comment: What is the FPS of the camera or video file? Use a mediaplayer like VLC or MPC-HC (look under **properties**). Do you have an example MP4 file to share (instead of image series, did you skip some images when sharing those JPGs)?

Comment: No, I don't have a video yet. I only took pictures at fixed intervals

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how slowly the crack forms, you probably don't need a video; you'll likely wind up sampling every X frames *anyway*, and throwing all of the extra frames away. What you want is enough frames to get "incremental" changes in the crack without getting too many frames that it becomes too computationally expensive.

1. If you can carefully control the lighting conditions in your setup, then you're in luck! This becomes a very simple problem. You can take a histogram of the pixels (openCV has handles for this, but so does PIL and numpy); you should get two families of color; one that is the color of the outside of the substance, and another that is biased by the shadow in the crack.

   You can also try dramatically increasing the contrast in each image/frame in order to get a binary mask of the crack, or running an [edge detector](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/canny_detector/canny_detector.html) over the image. These techniques will lead to frames that are substantially easier to process than the raw footage. You can even feed these into a skeletonization process in order to generate a vector-based representation of the line, in XY image coordinates.
2. If you can't control the lighting, or the sample is a similar color to the crack, you'll probably need to use [object detection](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/d54/group__objdetect.html) techniques, but it's unlikely there's an existing "crack detector," so you may either need to build your own, or look for what other detectors serve as a good proxy for the color and shape of the forming crack.

I'd highly recommend trying the first option if at all possible; pixel and histogram math is far easier than other techniques.

Comment: link to the series of images taken - https://drive.google.com/open?id=189cv8B4rm3lhSgT6OYfI_aN0Xmqi-tYi

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how the histogram of pixels for each image frame helps measure the rate of growth?

Comment: If you subtract the initial image's histogram from a subsequent image, the only pixels that are different should ostensibly be those involved in the crack. I'll try to draft up a brief example today.

Comment: I understand that there would be a larger number of 'crack' pixels in subsequent images when the crack has grown. So we'd be able to find that the crack grows x pixels/ time unit ? I was just wondering, the way speed of cars is estimated(i don't know how it is).. if that can be applied here.. Reading up on this..

Comment: There actually exist many detectors. The scientific literature is full of them. This problem has been addressed so often...

Answer (score 0):

With a proper segmentation approach you are going to have a detailed geometry of the object extracted from a single frame. For example:

[image]

If you process multiple frames you will be able to see geometry evolution in time. Having that it should be easy to compare polygons to find form changes, cracks, etc:

[image]

I used to work with 4K video to get all required details and good accuracy. You might not need all that data, but video is still way more flexible.

Here is a complete example: https://youtu.be/g2KyfrBtTA4

Provide some examples if you want to get more detailed recommendations.

**Update**

Real examples are always helpful. So you can segment a crack:

[image]

or a substance:
[image]

or both:
[image]

Basically, you need to enhance overall quality of the input (focus, background under the substance, etc).

As Mark Setchell showed, you might get unwanted background as part of the result shape (the right side of the crack), so it is better to make sure that will not happen or just try to analyze only the substance.

Anyway, your task doesn't seem to be complex. It might be trivial if you can improve image quality and do some simplifications to the environment (some specific background, etc).

Comment: link to series of images taken - https://drive.google.com/open?id=189cv8B4rm3lhSgT6OYfI_aN0Xmqi-tYi

Comment: How can this be achieved? is there a library to help find integrity of an object in an image?

Comment: I use a custom solution (see updated results), but OpenCV will do the trick as well. BTW, is it possible to get a short 4K video of the process?  I can segment it to find out how accurate a result can be.

Comment: It might be better to have a contrast sheet or something similar under the substance, so there will be no need to do a floodfill :)

Comment: But, after segmentation is the real problem.. how do I calculate how fast the crack grows automatically? I currently measure manually, but want to automate the measurement.

Comment: @aneeshaasc, if you manage to get a video with a predefined frame rate (30 fps, for example) it will be possible to calculate the difference between two frames and that difference will be for 1/30 second

Comment: Can you please share the code used to perform this segmentation?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any code to share, I just used a custom UI tool to process your examples.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate you are only just getting started but you have some issues with your video. Firstly the lighting  it is not best and it is not consistent because people are moving around in front of it and casting shadows - it also doesn't illuminate the the background behind the crack best - it would be better if it was at the height of the crack and shining more into it so that it better illuminates the background behind the crack. Secondly, you could do without the camera moving part way through the experiment!

Finally, if you want to measure things you need to calibrate, which at the very least means putting a ruler in the image - or scale lines on your background at fixed intervals. If you are doing all that you may as well make life easy for yourself and put markers of a specific colour/pattern, both different, on the top and bottom of the frame plates that are applying the load.

Finally then, you want to do something like a floodfill, or a fill just within the confines of your material (probably by masking) to fill the crack with a different colour. It is then pretty simple to measure the length of the crack and the left-most extent of the crack.

[image]

Comment: Could you please advise how I can do this floodfill to fill up the crack as you've shown? Also, once filled, if I need to determine how fast the crack grows or the tip of the crack moves across frames, how do I go about it? Kindly advise.

Comment: It depends which package you use. On ImageMagick in Terminal, you want something like `magick input.jpg -fill magenta -fuzz 50% -draw "color 588,255 floodfill" result.png` which fills with magenta all pixels starting at [x,y]=[588,255] that are within 50% of the brightness of the colour of that pixel. With OpenCV, you want to use this https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=floodfill#floodfill

Comment: You measure the rate (i.e. speed) as `distance`/`time` where you extract the distance as I have mentioned above and the time from the video timecode.

Comment: I'm trying to make provision for having markers on the frame plates. Post this, how do I determine if the edge of the crack has reached a marker line in each image frame? Can this be done using python/opencv programming? Kindly excuse if my questions are too abc.. I haven't coded much.

Comment: Also, how did you create a mask for the floodfill? kindly advise.

Comment: Start simply. Just make a black image in Photoshop or Paint and draw a red line on it. Try to open it in OpenCV. Try to locate all the red pixels. Find the total area of the red pixels. Try to find the left-most red pixel. Then the rightmost. Determine the length of the red line. Knowing the length and the area, work out the average width. Draw a fatter line and see if its width comes out wider. Try to find a coloured marker.... ask on Stack Overflow if stuck. It's free!

Comment: There's no mask for floodfill, it just *"floods"* into similarly coloured touching pixels... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

Comment: Python: cv2.floodFill(image, mask, seedPoint, newVal[, loDiff[, upDiff[, flags]]]) → retval, rect

Comment: Not in v4 https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.2/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#gaf1f55a048f8a45bc3383586e80b1f0d0 but just set it totally permissive initially and then close down the boundaries you don't want it to cross later.

Comment: I upgraded to v4, but still got asked for the mask. https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1-I9KyosC8QPogPNoLEV4-41YCQ1IYHKg shows what I tried to make it work with a mask I created. The resultant image is not segmented, it just turns black. Kindly advise.

Comment: Can you please share the code used to perform this segmentation?

Comment: Unfortunately not, one of the algorithms in there is proprietary. Sorry.

Comment: what parameters did you use for floodfill? I have been unable to get a clean fill as you've shown. I currently use :  num,im,mask,rect = cv2.floodFill(resized, mask, (0,0), (255,0,0), (10,)*3, (10,)*3, floodflags)